# localized srandom?

Tags: random, local, seed

I'm using std::random_shuffle and srandom, and wonder if it's possible to constrain srandom()'s effect to local block of code.

To be more precise, 
For a server application, I need to have different random seeds for different clients and keep using this pre-determined seed for random number generation per clients.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routines you are looking for are `srandom_r(3)` and `random_r(3)`:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/random_r.3.html

Comment: ah thanks, can I use it for random_shuffle() as well? looks like i could