# Is there a thread-safe srandom() on MacOS?

Tags: multithreading, macos, random

I'm working on some code to generate some artistic images. Part of the process is random. The user can set the random seed in order to get a repeatable result.

I'm seeing that I don't get the same results if I generate 2 images at the same time with the same parameters on different threads. I suspect this is because `srandom()`/`random()` aren't thread safe.

It appears [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062474/localized-srandom) that Linux has the additional `srandom_r()` and `random_r()` methods which are reentrant. But I cannot find those on MacOS.

From reading the man page of `srandom()`/`random()`, I see there is also `initstate()` and `setstate()`, but it's not clear from the man page that using them will fix the issue. Is that their purpose?

I could use a [`Mersenne Twister`](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html), but was hoping there was something native to the OS I could use. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Why not just use arc4random ?

Comment: Because I need to be able to seed it with the user-chosen seed so they can get the same results for the same input. I don't see a way to seed `arc4random()`. Is there one?

Comment: ah, I missed that. hmm, at least there is an AIX man page that says http://ps-2.kev009.com/tl/techlib/manuals/adoclib/libs/basetrf2/random.htm  don't use the initstate or setstate functions in a multi-threaded env.

Comment: As long as nobody calls `lcong48()` you could use `jrand48()`, but it's a different (worse) generator.